# log4net is not logging anything nor creating the file

Tags: c#, wpf, logging, nuget, log4net

I'm trying to configure log4net in my WPF application but I'm struggling to do so. I have read all the questions about it here but none resolved my issue. Find the code down below.

log4net NuGet version: 2.0.8

**AssemblyInfo.cs**

```
using System.Windows;

[assembly: ThemeInfo(
    ResourceDictionaryLocation.None, //where theme specific resource dictionaries are located
                                     //(used if a resource is not found in the page,
                                     // or application resource dictionaries)
    ResourceDictionaryLocation.SourceAssembly //where the generic resource dictionary is located
                                              //(used if a resource is not found in the page,
                                              // app, or any theme specific resource dictionaries)
)]
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(Watch = true)]
```

**App.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" />
    </configSections>
    <log4net>
        <appender name="LogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
            <param name="File" value="C:\Mylogs\Installer.log" />
            <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
            <appendToFile value="true" />
            <rollingStyle value="Size" />
            <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
            <maximumFileSize value="1MB" />
            <staticLogFileName value="true" />
            <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
                <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %level %logger - %message%newline" />
            </layout>
        </appender>
        <root>
            <level value="ALL" />
            <appender-ref ref="LogFileAppender" />
        </root>
    </log4net>
</configuration>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
using log4net;
...
public partial class MainWindow
{
    ...
    private static readonly ILog Log = LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
    ...
    private void BtnChangeLocation_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ...
        Log.Debug("This is a Debug message");
        Log.Info("This is a Info message");
        Log.Warn("This is a Warning message");
        Log.Error("This is an Error message");
        Log.Fatal("This is a Fatal message");
    }
}
```

When I run the application and click on the button (BtnChangeLocation_Click) no file is created, or even if I create the file manually, nothing is inserted into it. What could be the problem?

Comment: Can you try to update the "ConversionPattern" to <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d [%t] %-5p %c %m%n"/>

Comment: @ScareCrow Didn't help.

Comment: I believe the file has the write permission. Please check that too.

Comment: @ScareCrow If you mean `Installer.log`, then it does have a Write permission. I have also tried to run the application as an administrator, but it all go to the same result.

Comment: Are you sure you can write to `C:\Mylogs` directory? Sometimes the root of C is protected from non-admin programs trying to put things there. If you change `C:\Mylogs\Installer.log` to just `Installer.log` then check your debug directory for that file after you run it. I just started a brand new WPF app, copy and pasted everything you have in to mine and it worked perfectly with no modifications.

Comment: What returns `System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType`? Try to replace that with some string, i.e.: `"MyLogger"`

Comment: Please, read this: [Log4net Tutorial](https://stackify.com/log4net-guide-dotnet-logging/)

Comment: I have tried to do all the steps again as in @MaciejLos tutorial and the logging is finally working. Thank you so much, please create an answer to mark an issue as resolved and to claim the bounty.

Comment: @Chyuae, glad to hear that. An answer has been added. ;)

Comment: @MaciejLos Bounty will be available in 11 hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest to read this: [Log4net Tutorial](https://stackify.com/log4net-guide-dotnet-logging/).

There you'll find 14 steps to do to properly install and configure log4Net NuGet package.

One of the most important steps to do is to add `log4net.config` file, then to add an entry to `AssemblyInfo.cs` file... Follow the link for further details.

Good luck!